# Not able to retrieve value of prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, jsx, react-component

First time posting on here, so hopefully I explain this right...I'm building a multi-step form in React, and I want to display a variable number of input fields in one of those steps. The number of fields required is set in the state of a class component.

The code works as planned when I just enter a number i.e. renders what I want it to, but not when I try to declare 'num' as props.number

It doesn't throw an error, just displays nothing. Seems to retrieve the value of props.currentStep just fine. In fact, if i let num = props.currentStep, it renders the corresponding number of fields.

```
    function Step2(props) {
      let num = props.number;
      let i = 0
      if (props.currentStep !== 2) {
        return null
      } 
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>
            {Array(num).fill().map(() => {
               i += 1
               return (
                 <div key={i}>
                   <TextField 1>
                   <TextField 2>
                 </div>
               )
             })
           }     
         </div>
       </React.Fragment>         
     )
   }
```

I also tried using a getter in the class component, and that logs the number correctly to the console, but I still can't get the value and use this in my function.

```
class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentStep: 1,
      number: 3,

      get Number() {
        let result = this.number;
        console.log(result);
        return result
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>       
          <form>     
            <Step1 
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
            />
            <Step2 
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
            />
            <Step3 
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
            />
          </form>
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Even with the getter, let num = props.Number does not work.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, or maybe just doing this completely the wrong way.

Trying to limit the volume of content here (also for fear of embarrassment), so haven't posted the entire code i.e. the handlechange, and next/previous step functions etc. but let me know if you need more info to answer this question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass the 'number' prop to Step2 component.

```
<Step2 currentStep={this.state.currentStep} number={this.state.number} />;
```

Comment: Thank you... now I see what I was missing. Once I added number=this.state.number to the rendered component, I could get the value in my function using props.number (the same as I was doing with props.currentStep already. I'm new to react, and I was focusing on the wrong thing trying to solve this! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In you **Step2** component you are not passing a prop called **number** instead you are passing a prop called **currentStep**. Try passing the number to the component like this

```
<Step2 currentStep={this.state.currentStep} number={this.state.number} />;
```

What is the purpose of the function

```
  get Number() {
    let result = this.number;
    console.log(result);
    return result
  }
```

you don't need to have something like this instead you can access the number as `this.state.number`. and if you want to change it create a function like this

```
changeNumber=(number)=> this.setState({number:number});
```